# Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 502 when connecting on azure with ocelot gateway

Tags: azure, websocket, signalr, ocelot

I am using signalR in my application and get error when upload ocelot gateway on azure portal

My ts code

```
this.hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl("https://url.azurewebsites.net/gatewayOcelot/notification", {
            skipNegotiation: true,
            transport: signalR.HttpTransportType.WebSockets
        })
        .build();
```

and ocelot route is

```
{
  "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/gatewayOcelot/{url}",
  "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "Get", "Put", "Delete", "Post", "Patch", "OPTIONS" ],
  "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/{url}",
  "DownstreamScheme": "wss",
  "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
    {
      "Host": "apiURL.com",
      "Port": 443
    }
  ],
  "HttpHandlerOptions": {
    "AllowAutoRedirect": true
  }
},
```

startup code

```
 app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
          
            endpoints.MapHub<NotificationHub>("/api/notification");
        });
```

get error

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://url.azurewebsites.net/gatewayOcelot/notification' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 502
```

Answer (score 0):

Just double checking: WebSocket needs to be configured on Ocelot:

```
 Configure(app =>
{
    app.UseWebSockets();
    app.UseOcelot().Wait();
})
```

and in ocelot.json

```
{
     "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/ws",
     "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/",
     "DownstreamScheme": "ws",
     "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
         {
             "Host": "localhost",
             "Port": 5001
         }
     ],
 }
```

[https://ocelot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/features/websockets.html#:~:text=Ocelot%20supports%20proxying%20websockets%20with,your%20application%20to%20use%20WebSockets](https://ocelot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/features/websockets.html#:%7E:text=Ocelot%20supports%20proxying%20websockets%20with,your%20application%20to%20use%20WebSockets).

Comment: I already add ocelot on startup
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {


            app.UseWebSockets();

            app.UseOcelot().Wait();

        }

Comment: then, you should insect diagnose an solve problems => availability and performance of your app service plan. ( 502 errors happens at IIS level )

Comment: diagnose and solve problem: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-diagnostics